# How do I make a button change color on another Form live

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I change the color of my mainUI(Form) from my Themes form live? I've tried doing it simple but it doesnt update it live. This is the code that I used

MainUI:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Themes theme = new Themes();
        theme.Show();
    }
```

Themes:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainUI n = new MainUI();
        n.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);           

    }
```

Comment: You need to pass a reference to your main form into your themes form. The way you do it now you're creating a new main form, not showing it and changing a butting color

Answer (score 0):

**Themes**

```
private MainUI _mainUI;

public Themes(MainUI mainUI)
{
   _mainUI = mainUI
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mainUI.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);           
}
```

**MainUI**

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Themes theme = new Themes(this);
    theme.Show();
}
```

---

If you want to access anything else, like buttons you will have to set them to public. However you can also create methods to do the same thing

**MainUI**

```
public void DoOotherStuff()
{
    // are your basses belong to us
}
```

**Themes**

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mainUI.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255); 
    _mainUI.DoOotherStuff();          
}
```

Comment: This line : _mainUI.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);  gets this error : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @Nerreg this line  `Themes theme = new Themes(this);` is very important

Comment: When I do Themes theme = new Themes(this) my form gets a completely different design.